# Kernel sees ttyACM2 but does not create an entry in /dev/

Tags: usb, tty, serial-port

When I plug an M5Stack [StampC3U](https://docs.m5stack.com/en/core/stamp_c3u) device in my Ubuntu machine, the kernel sees it, as dmesg will report:

```
cdc_acm 1-8:1.0: ttyACM2: USB ACM device
```

But to my surprise, the Arduino IDE does not let me select that port.

Upon further investigation, it turns out that the device file is missing from dev:

```
$ ls -al /dev/ttyACM*
crw-rw-rw- 1 root dialout 166, 0 Mar 21 13:52 /dev/ttyACM0
crw-rw-rw- 1 root dialout 166, 1 Mar 21 13:52 /dev/ttyACM1
```

It also does not show up with `hwinfo --short`

Where is the missing `/dev/ttyACM2` file?

Comment: Can you see your device in output of ` hwinfo --short` command?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that (unlike the [StampC3](https://docs.m5stack.com/en/core/stamp_c3)) the [StampC3U](https://docs.m5stack.com/en/core/stamp_c3u) by default does not enable the [USB CDC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_communications_device_class).

To enable it, the button hooked up to GPIO9 need to be held down while powering on.

To change this behaviour, there is an option in the Arduino IDE that can be enabled, so that holding the button is no longer required.

[image: arduino ide option]

With USB CDC enabled, the linux host will see:

```
usb 1-8: new full-speed USB device number 36 using xhci_hcd
usb 1-8: New USB device found, idVendor=303a, idProduct=1001, bcdDevice= 1.01
usb 1-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
usb 1-8: Product: USB JTAG/serial debug unit
usb 1-8: Manufacturer: Espressif
usb 1-8: SerialNumber: 60:55:F9:57:BD:1C
cdc_acm 1-8:1.0: ttyACM2: USB ACM device
```

and:

```
# ls -al /dev/ttyACM*
crw-rw-rw- 1 root dialout 166, 0 Mar 21 13:52 /dev/ttyACM0
crw-rw-rw- 1 root dialout 166, 1 Mar 21 13:52 /dev/ttyACM1
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 166, 2 Mar 23 11:49 /dev/ttyACM2
```